# Comparing multiple string value and store them in SET/Array

Tags: java, loops, set

I want to store the value of string as an array of elements/ or as a set, provided 1 or many string matches. Is it possible to achieve something this this?
Here is the pseudo code

```
for (String some_string : Name){

IF (some_string.equals("john" OR/AND "mary" OR/AND "peter" OR "etc."){
   THEN add them to SET/ Array
}}
```

Comment: To answer in simple way. Yes it is possible!

Comment: Can you provide any suggestions?

Comment: Any attempt from your end?

Comment: Check the Java doc. `Set` has a `contains` method.

Comment: This is a good question, but it sounds like you're asking us to do your homework for you. Next time try to write the code on your own and do some research about data structures in Java.

Answer (score -1):

```
public static void test()
     {
        HashSet<String> set = new HashSet<String>(); 
        set.add("john");
        set.add("peter");
        set.add("alex");
        HashSet<String> newlist = new HashSet<String>(); 

        for (String some_string : Name){

              if(set.contains(some_string)){
                  newlist.add(some_string);
              }
       }
     }
```

Comment: I am getting ```Name``` value from another method, is there any way to check for equality without storing them? As there may be n number of values

Comment: you can pass that list in this test method